# Flexmojos, includes tag and wildcard

Tags: apache-flex, flexmojos

I know I can link in in my SWF at compile time some classes with the flexmojos `includes` tag :

```
<includes>
    <include>my.package.MyClass</include>
</includes>
```

But is there a way to link in many classes with a wildcard directly ?

I tried :

```
<includes>
    <include>my.package.**</include>
    <include>my.package.*</include>
</includes>
```

but I receive this error :

> [ERROR] Unable to resolve a class for include: my.package.*.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Your script part like it: http://repository.sonatype.org/content/sites/flexmojos-site/4.0-beta-7/compile-swc-mojo.html#includeClasses ??

Comment: I already saw that but this code is for SWC files not for SWF files. When I test it, my classes are not included in my SWF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating a SWC file `compile-swc` goal and included this SWC file as a dependency with `internal` scope.

Now, it works, all files are included in my SWF at compile time.